# can you get results returned other than using pandas on yolov5?

Tags: python, pandas, yolov5

in yolov5 tutorial it says pandas().xyxy[0] to get results from inference.

```
results = model(testa) # inference

boxes = results.pandas().xyxy[0] # gets the results
```

but is it possible to use something else (like polars) than pandas to get the results returned? because using pandas is so slow and my code needs to be faster.
i'd appreciate if someone could tell me (a simple example would be nice too!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can process detections with NumPy. It is not clear what you desire. In my case, based on the detection class and X0 coordinate, I want to make a decision. The "boxes" array consists of bbox coordinates, confidence score and class id, respectively. I used the 'xywhn' format that returns normalized coordinates. So I check each row's last element and first element, and the "wanted" array returns the row index that satisfies the condition.

```
results = model(img)
boxes = results.xywhn[0].detach().cpu().numpy()
wanted = np.where(((boxes[:,-1] == 1) & (boxes[:,0] > 0.4)))

print(results)
print(wanted)

[[    0.64899     0.64092    0.096527     0.25932     0.92479           2]
 [    0.72146     0.70188    0.058451     0.14613     0.90287           1]
 [    0.71426       0.931    0.091868     0.11923     0.88958           3]]
(array([1]),)
```

This solution might work if you don't need to store detections and process them immediately.